# Reshaping a long format data frame to wide based on two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I am having a data frame as shown below:

```
dat <- data.frame(QuarterYear = c("Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", 
                              "Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", 
                              "Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", "Q4 2019", "Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", 
                              "Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", 
                              "Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", "Q1 2020", "Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", 
                              "Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", 
                              "Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", "Q2 2020", "Q3 2020", "Q3 2020", "Q3 2020", 
                              "Q3 2020", "Q3 2020", "Q3 2020", "Q3 2020", "Q3 2020", "Q3 2020", 
                              "Q3 2020", "Q3 2020", "Q3 2020"), 
              Grade = c("Grade 8", "Grade 8", 
                        "Grade 8", "Grade 9", "Grade 9", "Grade 9", "Grade 10", "Grade 10", 
                        "Grade 10", "Grade 11", "Grade 11", "Grade 11", "Grade 8", "Grade 8", 
                        "Grade 8", "Grade 9", "Grade 9", "Grade 9", "Grade 10", "Grade 10", 
                        "Grade 10", "Grade 11", "Grade 11", "Grade 11", "Grade 8", "Grade 8", 
                        "Grade 8", "Grade 9", "Grade 9", "Grade 9", "Grade 10", "Grade 10", 
                        "Grade 10", "Grade 11", "Grade 11", "Grade 11", "Grade 8", "Grade 8", 
                        "Grade 8", "Grade 9", "Grade 9", "Grade 9", "Grade 10", "Grade 10", 
                        "Grade 10", "Grade 11", "Grade 11", "Grade 11"), 
              Type = c("overallAverage", 
                       "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", 
                       "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", 
                       "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", 
                       "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", 
                       "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", 
                       "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", 
                       "CT", "RT", "overallAverage", "CT", "RT"), 
              value = c(2.48, 2.21, 
                        0.27, 3.48, 3.03, 0.45, 4.6, 4, 0.6, 2.8, 2.4, 0.4, 2.54, 2.28, 
                        0.26, 3.45, 3, 0.45, 4.46, 3.88, 0.58, 3.56, 2.81, 0.75, 2.47, 
                        2.14, 0.33, 2.96, 2.54, 0.41, 4.1, 3.69, 0.41, 3.44, 2.61, 0.83, 
                        2, 1.81, 0.19, 2.54, 2.26, 0.28, 4.11, 3.68, 0.43, 2.67, 2.11, 
                        0.56), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I am trying to reshape this data frame into a wide-format where unique values of `Type` will be the rows and the values will be filled based on the `QuarterYear` and `Grade`.

To put in the simple words, if the first row is `OverallAverage`, the first 4 columns will be representing `Q4 2019-Grade 8` to `Q3 2020- Grade 8`. The next 4 columns will be for `Q4 2019-Grade 9` to `Q3 2020-Grade 9` and so on.

I tried using the `reshape` function

```
widerDat <- reshape(dat, direction = "wide",idvar = "Type",timevar = "value")
```

How can I combine `QuarterYear` and `Grade` to get the required output?

Please help me arrive at a suitable solution. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Does this work? dat %>% pivot_wider(names_from = c(QuarterYear, Grade), values_from = value)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reshape data from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

Comment: @prosoitos Apparently not, OP experiences the special case of a split time variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could `paste` the time variables together and use it as a single `time=` variable like so:

```
res <- reshape(transform(dat, time=paste(QuarterYear, Grade)), 
               direction="wide", idvar="Type", timevar="time",
               drop=c("QuarterYear", "Grade"))  
res
#             Type value.Q4 2019 Grade 8 value.Q4 2019 Grade 9
# 1 overallAverage                  2.48                  3.48
# 2             CT                  2.21                  3.03
# 3             RT                  0.27                  0.45
#   value.Q4 2019 Grade 10 value.Q4 2019 Grade 11 value.Q1 2020 Grade 8
# 1                    4.6                    2.8                  2.54
# 2                    4.0                    2.4                  2.28
# 3                    0.6                    0.4                  0.26
#   value.Q1 2020 Grade 9 value.Q1 2020 Grade 10 value.Q1 2020 Grade 11
# 1                  3.45                   4.46                   3.56
# 2                  3.00                   3.88                   2.81
# 3                  0.45                   0.58                   0.75
#   value.Q2 2020 Grade 8 value.Q2 2020 Grade 9 value.Q2 2020 Grade 10
# 1                  2.47                  2.96                   4.10
# 2                  2.14                  2.54                   3.69
# 3                  0.33                  0.41                   0.41
#   value.Q2 2020 Grade 11 value.Q3 2020 Grade 8 value.Q3 2020 Grade 9
# 1                   3.44                  2.00                  2.54
# 2                   2.61                  1.81                  2.26
# 3                   0.83                  0.19                  0.28
#   value.Q3 2020 Grade 10 value.Q3 2020 Grade 11
# 1                   4.11                   2.67
# 2                   3.68                   2.11
# 3                   0.43                   0.56
```

To order the columns in the desired format, we can use `substr`.

```
nm <- names(res)[-1]  ## store names in a vector
## generate order vector by relevant characters
o <- order(as.double(substr(nm, 21, 22)), as.double(substr(nm, 10, 13)),
           as.double(substr(nm, 8, 8))) + 1
res <- res[c(1, o)]  ## ordering
names(res)
#  [1] "Type"                   "value.Q4 2019 Grade 8"  "value.Q1 2020 Grade 8" 
#  [4] "value.Q2 2020 Grade 8"  "value.Q3 2020 Grade 8"  "value.Q4 2019 Grade 9" 
#  [7] "value.Q1 2020 Grade 9"  "value.Q2 2020 Grade 9"  "value.Q3 2020 Grade 9" 
# [10] "value.Q4 2019 Grade 10" "value.Q1 2020 Grade 10" "value.Q2 2020 Grade 10"
# [13] "value.Q3 2020 Grade 10" "value.Q4 2019 Grade 11" "value.Q1 2020 Grade 11"
# [16] "value.Q2 2020 Grade 11" "value.Q3 2020 Grade 11"
```

Comment: How can I get the consecutive columns based on the quarter for each grade? For instance, the column order will be Q4 2019 Grade 8, Q1 2020 Grade 8, Q2 2020 Grade 8, Q3 2020 Grade, Q4 2019 Grade 9 going on.

Comment: @NevedhaAyyanar Usng `substr`, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do

```
library(tidyverse)

wider_data <- dat %>% mutate(new_col = paste(Grade,QuarterYear, sep = " ")) %>%
  select(Type, new_col, value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = new_col, values_from = value)
```

for re-arranging the columns manually, use this

```
wider_data <- wider_data %>% select(1,2,6,10,14,3,7,11,15,4,8,12,16,5,9,13,17)
```